I get configure error when i try to launch my site in debug mode
Here's my manage.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'webstore.settings')  # webstore is project name
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Here's the error:

ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested settings, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I've tried to set environment manually, nothing changed

How are you running the application?

I tried to debug code in pycharm.

What is PyCharm configuration to debug your app?

Uhmm.. It says 'current file'
